# ~200ms delay in Windows Sockets - why?

Tags: windows, performance, tcp

[image: Wireshark Excerpt]
I have a performance problems with a TCP connection on Windows. My server sends a message to my client (frame 1049), which the client is supposed to answer immediately. The client does answer the message, but only with a delay of 188ms (frame 1057).

The PSH bit of the server message is set.

Since 188ms is pretty close to 200ms, I thought that either the Nagle algorithm or Delayed ACKs are responsible. Setting TCP_NODELAY/disabling Nagle has no effect. Disabling Delayed ACKs, i.e. setting TcpAckFrequency to 1 on the network interface does have an effect; with this registry key set, the delay is gone.

However, I do not understand why. If I am not mistaken, there is no delayed ACK - the message from the server is acknowledged immediately in frame 1050! Could anybody explain what's happening here? I would also be very happy about a workaround other than setting the TcpAckFrequency, since this is a "global" hack which affects all connections on the network interface.

Comment: My immediate thought was "Nagle", then I saw the rest of the question. What is the buffer size of the machine(s)?

Comment: Never underestimate the ability of security software causing this delay.  Consider temporarily disabling anti-malware and firewall and what-not on both machines.

Comment: @AdamThomason: Both the send and receive buffer of the socket are 8192 byte.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. Also, I don't think that this causes the problem - otherwise, how would the TcpAckFrequency fix the problem...

Comment: @ChristophAlbert 8k should usually be completely acceptable. 16k would be my personal limit on buffer size, mostly because it's unlikely to ever be filled. Saying that, it might be worth upping to 16k just to ensure that the buffer isn't the issue?

Comment: @AdamThomason: I now experimented a little bit with the buffer sizes. Neither increasing the buffer to 16k nor decreasing it to 1k has a big effect.